# Bash parameter substitution mess (pdfgrep, regex, newline and more)

Tags: regex, bash

I need to match a pattern across multiple lines with pdfgrep

```
pdfgrep -in -C line 'CHAPTER 1'[$'\n'][$' ']*'THIS IS THE TITLE' ~/temp.pdf
```

works ok and outputs

```
12:                                 CHAPTER 1
                  THIS IS THE TITLE
```

Now

```
$ pattern="CHAPTER 1 - THIS IS THE TITLE"
$ echo "'${pattern:0:9}'[$'\n'][$' ']*'${pattern:12:${#pattern}}'"
'CHAPTER 1'[$'\n'][$' ']*'THIS IS THE TITLE'
$ pdfgrep -in -C line "'${pattern:0:9}'[$'\n'][$' ']*'${pattern:12:${#pattern}}'" ~/temp.pdf
```

doesn't work anymore, gives me nothing. I guess there is something going on with the parameter substitution, but I can't figure out what's happening. Anyone can help?

Background infos:

From "man pdfgrep"

```
pdfgrep works much like grep, with one distinction: It operates on pages and not on lines.
```

"." matches any character, line breaks INCLUDED.

Comment: Your `echo` doesn't match the output - you're using `pattern1` instead of `pattern`. Is this only a typo in the question, or also in reality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using extra `'` characters:

```
"'${pattern:0:9}'[$'\n'][$' ']*'${pattern:12:${#pattern}}'"
 ^              ^              ^                         ^
```

Also, you are using `$'\n'` and `$' '` inside double quotes, and this prevents their expansion.

**The correct expression is:**

```
"${pattern:0:9}"[$'\n'][$' ']*"${pattern:12:${#pattern}}"
```

In fact:

```
$ echo 'CHAPTER 1'[$'\n'][$' ']*'THIS IS THE TITLE'
CHAPTER 1[
][ ]*THIS IS THE TITLE

$ pattern="CHAPTER 1 - THIS IS THE TITLE"
$ echo "${pattern:0:9}"[$'\n'][$' ']*"${pattern:12:${#pattern}}"
CHAPTER 1[
][ ]*THIS IS THE TITLE
```

Note that the output of `echo` when given the two expressions is the equivalent (if you did things right, `echo` should *not* return a Bash expression, it should return the final string).

---

It's not required, but as a best practice you should quote the `*`, `[` and `]` characters (thanks [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225894/bash-parameter-substitution-mess-pdfgrep-regex-newline-and-more/32226060#comment-52344972) for noticing). Also, `$' '` is pretty useless here:

```
"${pattern:0:9}["$'\n'"][ ]*${pattern:12:${#pattern}}"
                ^     ^  ^
```

This will prevent glob expansion (which is unlikely to happen in your case, but still something to care about).

Comment: :D you are right. I got tricked because I had to put quotes around 'CHAPTER 1' and 'THIS IS THE TITLE' in order to avoid confusion with spaces, and I thought that substituting the exact same string would have worked.

Comment: The `[` and `]` should be quoted as well; they form valid patterns that the shell could interpret (although it's unlikely this pattern will match a file name. `'CHAPTER 1['$'\n '']*THIS IS THE TITLE...'`

Answer (score 1):

$'\n' doesnt interpolates to the line feed when the string is double-quoted:

```
prompt $ echo "$'\n'"
$'\n'
prompt $ echo $'\n'
```

Don't use double-quotes around the string:

```
prompt $ a='abcd'$'\n''efgc'
prompt $ echo "$a"
abcd
efgc
```

P.S. Your regular expression looks very strange. Why do you use square brackets around the \n and \s?

Comment: I started with the much simpler `pdfgrep -in "CHAPTER 1\n *THIS IS THE TITLE" ~/temp.pdf`,  then `pdfgrep -in "CHAPTER 1$'\n'$' '*THIS IS THE TITLE" ~/temp.pdf`, then `pdfgrep -in "CHAPTER 1[$'\n'][$' ']*THIS IS THE TITLE" ~/temp.pdf`and nothing seemed to work. I builded it up again putting extra quoting, but I really can't figure out why these simpler expressions didn't work.

Comment: I tried again and the simpler `pdfgrep -in "CHAPTER 1"$'\n'$' '"*THIS IS THE TITLE" ~/temp.pdf`works!

Comment: @the_eraser: if you want to simplify it even more, remove `$' '` and use `"CHAPTER 1"$'\n'" *THIS IS THE TITLE"` instead.

Comment: Yeah I did it. I'm starting to get the hang of shell scripting that in some cases is very tricky due to pattern globbing, regex, strong quoting, weak quoting, many substitutions... sometimes all together. Thx,Luca.